# How to go to a sheet by sheetname?

Tags: libreoffice

I have around 300-400 sheets in a Libreoffice Calc file.

I have tried everything and I can't seem to go to a particular sheet by its name, that is the sheet is named: `XYZ` and when I try to find it using XYZ there are no results.

How do I go to a sheet by its name?

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic* and add this code.

```
Sub gotoSheet
    sName = InputBox("Which sheet?")
    oSheet = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByName(sName)
    ThisComponent.CurrentController.setActiveSheet(oSheet)
End Sub
```

Then go to *Tools -> Customize* and attach the macro to a toolbar button or hotkey.

Other options for going to a particular sheet more easily, such as using the Navigator list or creating hyperlinks, are described at:

- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/10650/jumping-sheet-tabs/
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/167878/where-is-the-goto-function-within-calc/

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a macro. Just use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+F5 to jump to the name box, type the (whole) sheet name and press enter.